# Common fixed points for a family of functions between cardinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a cardinal $k$, by $k^+$ we mean the lower cardinal bigger than $k$. By countinuous functions between ordinals we mean functions which commute with $\sup$ when applied to limit ordinals.

Let $F$ be a family of cardinality $k$ of increasing and continuous functions 
 $f:k^{+} \rightarrow k^+$. If $|F|\leq k$, then $F$ has common fixed points.

In particular the cardinality of this set of common fixed points is $k^+$.

In the case $|F|=1$ the answer is simple, because we can iterate the function.

Comment: Isn't a fixpoint of $g\circ f$ also a fixpoint of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Of course it is, that's embarassing

Comment: Do you know what are clubs (closed and unbounded sets)?

Comment: See [*The common points of families of normal functions*](https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1973-051-5) by Alexander Abian (1973), which is freely available on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably used to constructing fixed points via the following observation: that the limit of $$\alpha,F(\alpha), F(F(\alpha)), ...$$ is a fixed point of $F$, for any $\alpha$, if $F$ is increasing and continuous.

This isn't the best result to use here, however: the better one is the following:

> Suppose $F$ is increasing and continuous. If $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, ...)$ is an increasing sequence of ordinals with limit $\beta$, and $\alpha_{i+1}\ge F(\alpha_i)$, then $F(\beta)=\beta$.

The proof is basically the same, and this version gives you more flexibility in constructing fixed points. For instance, here's how to do the two-function version: suppose I have two increasing continuous functions $F, G$. Think about the sequence $0, F(0), G(F(0)), F(G(F(0))), ...$. What can you say about the limit of this sequence?

Now, do you see how to generalize this to arbitrary families of functions (of appropriate size)? *HINT*: think about limits of sequences longer than $\omega$ ...

Comment: What if i define the sequence $a_{i+1}=\sup\{f(a_i) |  f \in F\}$?
Clearly $a_{i+1} \geq f(a_i) \ \forall f \in F$, so $\forall f \in F\  f(\beta)=\beta$. Is it correct?